# Can backbone send data as multipart?

Tags: forms, backbone.js

Can Backbone send data as `multipart/form-data`? I believe it defaults to `application/json`. I looked through the documentation and if I do `Backbone.emulateJSON = true` it'll send as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but that doesn't help.

I'm working on a legacy project and I'm trying to add file-upload functionality to it. To do that though I'm told the server needs to be changed to accept *multiform* data rather than *application/json* data.

Answer (score 1):

When you `fetch`, `save`, etc. you can optionally provide an `options` argument.  Any options in it that aren't Backbone-specific ones (eg. `silent: true`) will be passed along to `sync`, which well then pass them along to `$.ajax`.

So, in short, you can do anything you could normally do with `$.ajax` by just passing the appropriate options when you make your Backbone AJAX method call.

Comment: And what are the appropriate options when you want to save a multipart ?

Comment: I would recommend looking at this SO question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

You can send data as mutipart by appending data to FormData() object ,and making your form enctype="multipart/form-data".You can also send File object through this.

```
<form class="form form-inline" id="quotation_form" method="post" data-remote="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

 </form>


     var data = new FormData();
     data.append("description", description);


      quotationAttachmentModel.save(null, {
             processData: false,
             url: requestURL,
             data: data,
             cache: false,
             iframe: true,
             emulateJSON: true,
             contentType: false,

      success: function(model, resp) {
        console.log("success");
      },
      error: function(data, jqXHR, errorThrown) {
        console.log("failed");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do the file upload using an explicit transport, e.g. jQuery.ajax or similar, as the uploads don't really resemble Backbone.Models anyway.
Also, you might want to use a library such as [jquery-fileupload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) and subscribe to the events it emits. Also check this for [ideas](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Submit-files-asynchronously).